# MySQL possible LIKE filter taking too much time

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have several tables and I need to join them. One of the tables has 200k records (this is a students table). Another one has over 1m records.

I need to filter by student entry year. On this scenario, the entry year is given by the first two digits of the student ID. The student ID has 6 digits.

For example: 
- Students from the year 1997 have the ID 97XXXX
- Students from the year 2005 have the ID A5XXXX
- Students from the year 2011 have the ID B1XXXX

So, I take that field and I use a LIKE statement.

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE id LIKE '97%'
```

... For students from the year 1997.

It turns out that this query is taking an awful amount of time. This is the EXPLAIN output for that specific table:

```
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | STUDENTS  | range | ID             | ID | 11      | NULL| 6505 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

Is it justifiable to transform or add an extra column to the DB with the year as a numeric value? Will that make the query a lot faster?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It will run even faster if you index the new field.  None of us are in a position to say whether or not it's justified.  You are the one who knows the requirements.

Comment: what are the tables and indices definitions now? What is the query? What does the query plan look like?

Comment: By query plan, do you mean the EXPLAIN?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on `id`?  MySQL should be able to optimize your query with such an index (as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)).

With the index, you could also try:

```
where id >= '97' and id < '98'
```

Comment: Of course, but the problem is that the id isn't numerical. For example if I need to look for the students of year 2006, I need to take a look onto the first two digits of that ID, and I am getting the student from 2006 (they start with A6 in this case) as a LIKE statement.

Comment: @Dynelight . . . I don't understand your comment.  Comparisons work on strings as well as numbers.

Comment: I want to get the students from the year 2006. How would you make the comparison?

Comment: It would be `id >= 'A6' and id < 'A7'`.

Comment: But the ID field has 6 digits. Would it work if I did: id >= 'A60000' and id < 'A70000' ?

Comment: @Dynelight . . . You can do that if you want, but for string comparisons that is not necessary.

Comment: And this is a lot faster than LIKE, yes? Even if that field has an index, will the performance of those operators be faster than LIKE?

Comment: Would it work if I made id >= '99' and id < 'A0' for students in year 1999? I guess I need to look into string comparisons using the greater/lesser operator.

Comment: @Dynelight . . . They should be the same with an index.

Comment: Anyway I do have an index on ID.